# How to get multiple values and store to database using laravel/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following jQuery code which I can get my HTML elements through this loop. I want to get my data and store it to a database via AJAX. How can I do it?

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
  for(var increment = 0; increment <= pos_inc; increment++) {
    var text1 = $('#orders' + increment).val();
    var text2 = $('#item_quan' + increment).val();
    var text3 = $('#price_tot' + increment).val();
  }
});
```

HTML

```
   <table class="table dynamic_field">                        
   <label>OR Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="sp_or"><?php echo $or_no; ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <br>
   <br>
   Sold To:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="sp_name"><?php echo $name; ?></span></label>
   <thead>
   <th>Items</th>
   <th>Qty</th>
   <th>Total</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {{ csrf_field() }}
  <!-- empty -->
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- hidden input-->
  <input type="hidden" id="inc" value="<?php echo $inc; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="or" name="or">
  <input type="hidden" id="cus_name" name="cus_name">
  <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total">
  <!-- end of hidden input-->

  <label>TOTAL:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="sp_tot"><?php echo $total; ?></span></label>
  <br>
  <label>CUSTOMER CHANGE:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $change; ?></label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="{{ url('use-pos') }}">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</button>
  </a>&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Complete Purchase" id="btnSubmit">
</form>
```

in my controller:

```
public function DoAddSales(Request $request){
    return $request->all();
}
```

Comment: Assuming they're all in the same form, just `$('#yourForm').serialize()` should do it. If that doesn't work for you, then you'll need to provide much more useful information, such as your HTML and full JS, along with the format your server is expecting to receive the data in

Comment: Show us the form HTML + controller function !

Comment: Were is the header of your form ??

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution,

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
  for(var increment = 0; increment <= pos_inc; increment++)
  {

      var text1 = $('#orders'+increment).val();
      var text2 = $('#item_quan'+increment).val();
      var text3 = $('#price_tot'+increment).val();

  }

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "yoururlhere",
      data: "{'text1':'" + text1+ "', 'text2':'" + text2+ "', 'text3':'" + text3+ "'}",
      success: function (result) {
           //do somthing here
      }
 }); 

});
```